# Parse function, and generics type guards

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-generics

i am making a ts module for myself, and I need a bit of help to make a function that parses & maps a list of strings to an object. This should be pretty easy, but what I wanted to do was to extend with typescript functionality and have it return a type. For this I used generics. My question is how do I type validate the object created to the interface, since I have to idea what keys there will be in the object & i have no clue what the types of those keys will be?

**Update**

```
async function parse<T extends GenericArg>(args: string[], keys: Array<keyof T>):Promise<T> {

var obj:T & any = {Other: ""}
//does the whole transformation, using the keys argument, and the args 
// argument for the array of strings that are actually maped

// here I need to do something to validate that the obj is conforming to type T

return obj

}
```

Comment: can you please give me practical example??

Comment: I have an array with strings in it, that i want to map onto an object, with a predefined type. However during the mapping process it has a little check or 10 that transfer that string into another type. At the end I need the object to be verefied that all the types & keys are corresponding to the original interface

Comment: what am i trying to say that please give me the code example

Comment: @PranshuShah check update ^^

Comment: higher kind of types are not supported in typescript. [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213)

Comment: huh wdym? Can you explain what you mean by "higher kind of types"